# XMLHttpRequest doesn't update in javascript's interval

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I use AJAX to check user updates every 2 seconds, but my javascript does not update the response.

I have one javascript file with XMLHttpRequest object and every 2 seconds it sends a request to another file (.php) where it gets XML with updates. For some reason, it doesn't always get the newest content and seems to have some old cached.

My javascript file contains this code (simplified):

```
var updates = new XMLHttpRequest();
updates.onreadystatechange = function(){
    "use strict";
    if(updates.readyState === 4 && updates.status === 200){
        console.log(updates.responseXML);
    }
};

var timer = 0;
clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(function(){
    "use strict";
    updates.open('GET','scripts/check_for_notifications.php', true);
    updates.send();
},2000);
```

Then I have the PHP file (*check_for_notifications.php*), where I have this code:

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$update = $response->addChild('update');
$update->addChild('content', 'New message');
$update->addChild('redirect', 'some link');
$update->addChild('date', '1.1.2019 12:00');

header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($response->asXML());
```

Every two second I receive a log in my console, but when I change the PHP file, while the interval is in progress (*e.g. I change the date to '1.1.2019 11:00' and save it*) I still receive the '12:00' in the console. For me, it seems that it doesn't update and it still has the *repsonseXML* cached. Is there any way I could "flush" the output or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You should do the updates.open(...) and updates.send() in the onreadystatechange event function instead of the timer. The http request might take longer than 2 seconds and your results are going roller coaster. And just do the "use strict" once at the documents beginning. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/9rswqhk2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a cache problem. In the network browser console, you should see a response of type 304 Not modified.

To be sure, you can add an element in the url to bypass the cache:

```
updates.open('GET','scripts/check_for_notifications.php&nocache=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

If this works, you will need to configure the server (apache or nginx) to prevent the file from being cached. It's cleaner than the timestamp solution. the browser does not store cached files unnecessarily.

Apache .htaccess or Apache conf, something like

```
<Files "check.php">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
    </IfModule>
</Files>
```

Nginx conf, something like

```
location = /check.php {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
    expires off;
}
```

You can also see the fetch api : https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/

**Be careful with your code, it can launch several requests simultaneously and find yourself with a DOS if there are too many users.**

**If requests take more than 2 seconds because the server is slow, others requests will be sent in the meantime, which will slow down the server even more....**

Comment: That "nocache + time trick" works, it was indeed cached (I checked the console). Is it okay to leave it with the nocache?

Comment: Normally, there are no security concerns when using a URL parameter to bypass the cache.
But it is not a clean and beautiful solution.
Normally, the cache must be managed by the server and browser. This allows you to set a cache duration, and the browser not to keep unnecessary files in its temporary folder.
There, it will keep each file in the temporary folder of the browser (index.html?nocache=1, index.html?nocache=2). Then, the method doesn't work if you make 500 requests every millisecond, but it can allow you to create caches of 5s (new Date().getTime() %(5*1000))

Comment: Thanks. On one hand, the responses are really small files (in bytes), but I get the deal of storing each file. I got there a timeout of 2 seconds before another call, but that’s not a solution (more like delaying the problem). I am going to find something about the server cache settings, but the code is running on a webhosting and I’m not quite sure how far can I go with the settings. Do you have any idea how to disable cache for this particular file?

Comment: It depends of the host you have. Normally, you have a minimum access to the configuration. I updated my answer.

Comment: I saw your update. I don’t understand htaccess rules too much, but wouldn’t it affect the whole server? I mean - only this one file is important for me to not to be cached. Is it possible to “flush” particular file from browser temp folder?